# How to update element of any particular index in an array in MongoDb using mongoose in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I tried to update the element at a particular index in an array but I'm not able to update it. It is updating the entire array. Not able to figure out how to update any particular index which is being passed by user. Let say user pass index from frontend as 1 then only the element at index 1 in appointment array gets updated not other.
Let say I have a schema in which I have Data who's type is array and default value is as shown below or anything in the same format.

```
Data: {
  type: Array,
  Default: ["0","1","0"]
}
```

Whenever I'll create a user then Data field will contain these default values, But now I want to update the value at index 1 of Data array of any user created.

I tried `findByIdAndUpdate` method but I don't know what to pass in set property. If I'm passing this {$set: req.body} and In postman I'm giving any value of Data then obviously it is updating Data array but I want to update value at any index how should I do that. What changes I have to make in `{$set : }`? Or any other method for that? Thanks in advance.

Waiting for any help or suggestions. Thanks

Comment: first find the user.  Then once you find the document you can do something like ` `const subDoc =user.keyName.id(passInTheIdOfTheSubdocument` then mutate the `subDoc` however you want then you can `save()` the document again